# Subset of a partially ordered set: Least upper bound and greatest lower bound.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

Let $(A, \leq)$ be a poset and $B \subseteq A$.
I need to show

i) B may have at most one least upper bound in A

ii) B may have at most one greatest lower bound in A.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is really a matter of unpacking and *applying the definitions* of what it means

- for $A$ to be a poset (**poset**: "[***partially ordered set***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poset)")

  - (See also the section of that entry subtitled [Extrema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poset#Extrema))
- for $B$ to be a *subset of $A$*,
- for a set to have a least upper bound (lub) and
- for a set to have greatest lower bound (glb).

Recall the definition of a *least upper bound* as:

Let *S* be a poset:

1. *$\alpha$* is an *upper bound* for *S* if $x \leq \alpha \space \forall x \in S$, (upper and lower bounds are NOT unique) and
2. $\beta$ is *the least upper bound* for *S* if $\beta$ is an *upper bound*, and $\beta \leq \alpha$ whenever $\alpha$ is an upper bound for *S*.

A symmetrical definition defines the *greatest lower bound*.

Comment: Sorry i m a newbie with this. I get the least upper bound but cant it it more than 1 least upper bound?

Comment: The least upperbound and the greatest lower bound are unique. But there can be infinitely many "upper" or "lower" bounds. We're interested here in the least/greatest (respectively) bounds.

Comment: Also note that you are asked to show that $B$ has at most one least upper bound *in A*, at most one greatest lower bound *in A*. It may be the case that ***no*** such lub or glb for $B$ exists in $A$, but if either does exist in A, then it is the unique lub/glb of $B$ in A, respectively. Make sure you're clear about such bounds for $A$, given it's a poset. Then figure out what this means with respect to lub/glb bounds for $B\subset A$.

Comment: How are you coming on this question, Ahmed?

Comment: still confused i m reading book right now. But still trying.

Comment: Sorry to be so stupid. I m so confused that i dont even know what to ask. I understand the definition. But i dont get why B can have atmost 1 glu and 1 lub in A

Comment: It isn't necessarily in A...But if B has a glb or lub, and it will be in A, which means it might be in B (and hence it would be in A, because $B\subseteq A$), or else it is $A-B \subset A$.

Comment: I tried my best do do this but I m still not getting it. Can u write me a complete answer for the  l.u.b???